# how sql query convert in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am trying to convert an SQL query to Linq

The query is :

```
 SELECT Distinct(InvoiceID)
 FROM Invoices
 WHERE ((DATEDIFF(day, InvoiceDate, GETDATE()) > PaymentDays)  AND
 status= 'false')
```

I have written the following code but not getting proper result....

```
var outstanding = db.Invoices.Where(t =>
     (t.InvoiceDate.Value.Subtract(DateTime.Today)).Days > t.PaymentDays.Value 
    && !(bool)t.Status)
```

In my opinion, DATEDIFF doesnt have proper equivalent in LINQ to SQL

Comment: Thats a lot of work, you should at least try it before - see examples here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746

Comment: Have you tried LinqPad which will help to create SQL and Linq queries?

Comment: Which part in particular are you having problems with?  Show us code describing how far you can get on your own (hint: start with `var result = from b in db.Buyer`), and tell is where you're getting confused, and which things you've tried that didn't work.

Comment: You can use a tool such as http://www.sqltolinq.com/ if you're struggling. However, it is well worth the time working through your problem and learning along the way.

Comment: @christofr: I think SQLTOLINQ will not translate DATEDIFF correctly

Answer (score 1):

I see a few problems with the code you've written.

- LinqToSql wont support `DateTime.Subtract`, for this sort of operation you'll need `SqlMethods.DateDiffDay` <sup>[docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468730.aspx)</sup>.
- The string "false" cannot be cast to a boolean, you need to either use `bool.Parse` or just compare to the string "false" as you did in your original.
- your original gets a distinct list of invoice id's. This is totally missing from your LINQ attempt. Append `.Select(t => t.InvoiceID).Distinct()` to your LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

```
DATEDIFF(day, InvoiceDate, GETDATE()) > PaymentDays
```

should translate to

```
DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1*PaymentDays) > InvoiceDate
```

**UPDATE**

this should fetch what you need

```
var outstanding = db.Invoices.Where(t => t.InvoiceDate.Value.AddDays(t.PaymentDays.Value) > DateTime.Today).Where(u => u.Status.Equals("false")).Select(v => v.InvoiceID).Distinct();
```

Comment: LinqToSql wont support any of the Add/Subtract methods on a datetime. Thats what `SqlMethods` fixes.

Comment: I can AddDays no problem to my sql-based datetime fields ... am i missing something ?

Comment: my bad, its all the datediff methods which dont work (hence the existence of `SqlMethods` which I linked in my answer).